# How can I automatically set tracking opt-out cookies in my browser?

Tags: firefox, security, browser, privacy, cookies

How can I have Firefox automatically set tracking opt-out cookies?

I've recently updated from Firefox 60 from Firefox 52esr, which means I've lost all my trusty [XUL add-ons](https://tech.slashdot.org/story/17/02/17/1635216/mozilla-will-deprecate-xul-add-ons-before-the-end-of-2017).  This includes [Beef Taco](http://jmhobbs.github.io/beef-taco/) (Targeted Advertising Cookie Opt-Out), which automatically set all of the tracking opt-out cookies from the [NAI Consumer Opt-out page](http://optout.networkadvertising.org/), even after cookies had been cleared.  It appears that add-on has not been redeveloped as a [WebExtension](https://wiki.mozilla.org/WebExtensions).

It's impractical for me to use the NAI page directly, since most of my cookies are cleared automatically when I exit my browser.  Are there any newer solutions to setting those cookies automatically, or are tracking opt-outs no longer advised or necessary?

I'm continuously running [Firefox Tracking Protection](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/tracking-protection), uBlock Origin, set the Do-Not-Track header, etc. but I liked the idea of having the opt-out cookies as last-ditch defense if a tracker slipped through those defenses.

Comment: Does the Do-Not-Track header cover what you want?

Comment: @jrtapsell No, it does not.  My understanding is that header is typically *ignored* by trackers, so it's useless.  These cookies are apparently their officially supported opt-out mechanism.

Comment: A first glance at teh BeefTaco site shows that it is not really rocket-science and under an apache licence. I am surprised that no-one webextension-ified it yet. Be aware that such an extension would need 'cookies' API permission and probably '*://*/*' host pemission (or something compiled from the list of some 450 builtin cookies). By the way, I'm afraid that list might be outdated (Jan 2013) ...

Comment: The industry-preferred method of using cookies to opt out of other cookies is intentionally broken due to cookie clearing and also due to what they can still do with your data even if you "opt out" (it doesn't prevent data collection typically, it only prevents visible signs of targeting ads to you). Better just to block 3rd-party trackers outright.